# How to cache ApplicationUser in Asp.NET Identity?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

We can obtain the `ApplicationUser` this way:

```
var owinContext = HttpContext.GetOwinContext();
var userManager = owinContext.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
var user = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());
```

For this we need to implement in our UserStore `IUserStore<TUser, in TKey>` this method:

```
Task<TUser> FindByIdAsync(TKey userId);
```

This method loads the application user via Database(in my case via Entity Framework). I will need this object in different tiers of my application. In its current state it will result in multiple database requests (for the same object) for only one web request.

What is the recommended way of caching this object?

I thought about a `Session` object, but i am 100 % sure, this would be stupid, because sometimes the user object can change (password, email, displayname etc).

Comment: Depending on what you need to keep in memory, you could also use `Claims`.

Comment: First, you probably shouldn't be passing an ApplicationUser to multiple tiers.  ApplicationUser is defined in your presentation tier, and passing it to other tiers means introducing a dependency upon your presentation tier in your lower tiers.  This is bad practice.  You should instead define a business object from your lower tiers that you pass to those tiers from your presentation tier that contains the required information.  And yes, never ever use Session for security purposes (besides, your other tiers should not have a dependency on Session either)

Comment: Hey @Erik F, what about use in multiple Controller action methods due to the `ApplicationUser` having extended properties that carry info that's atomic enough to pass to my service layer? e.g. a special Id that's assigned to many rows in some other table? (...as a reason to cache said AppUser instance)